# Как правильно организовать работу с сервером через сервис?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Есть приложение с несколькими активити, в каждой из которых по несколько фрагментов. Данные получаю с сервера. Вся работа с сервером организована в сервисе.

Вот код сервиса:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private volatile Socket socket;
    public final static String KEY_COMMAND_TYPE = "KEY_COMMAND_TYPE";
    public final static String KEY_COMMAND_GET_RESUMES = "KEY_COMMAND_GET_RESUMES";
    public static final String KEY_JSONSTRING = "KEY_JSONSTRING";
    public static final String KEY_HANDLER = "KEY_HANDLER";
    public static final int KEY_UPDATE = 1111;
    public static final int KEY_CONNECTED = 2222;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("MyLog", "onCreateMessangerService");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.e("MyLog", "connect");
                    int serverPort = 6666;

                    String address = "192.168.1.6";
                    try {
                        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);

                        socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort);

                        if(socket.isConnected()){
                            Message mesToActivity = WorkerFragment.handler.obtainMessage();
                            mesToActivity.what = KEY_CONNECTED;
                            WorkerFragment.handler.sendMessage(mesToActivity);
                        }

                        Scanner sc = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
                        while (true) {
                            String jsonString = sc.nextLine();
                            Log.e("MyLog", "Got a message from server. Length = " + String.valueOf(jsonString.length()));

                            Message mesToActivity = WorkerFragment.handler.obtainMessage();
                            mesToActivity.what = KEY_UPDATE;
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString(KEY_JSONSTRING, jsonString);
                            mesToActivity.setData(bundle);
                            WorkerFragment.handler.sendMessage(mesToActivity);

                            Log.e("MyLog", "Сообщение в активити отправлено.");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(intent != null) {
            Log.e("MyLog", "onStartCommand");

            final String command = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_COMMAND_TYPE);

            if (command != null && command.equals(KEY_COMMAND_GET_RESUMES)) {
                Log.e("MyLog", "if (command == KEY_COMMAND_GET_RESUMES)");
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (socket == null || socket.isClosed()) {
                            Log.e("MyLog", "Невозможно отправить данные. Сокет не создан или закрыт");
                            return;
                        }
                        try {
                            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                            pw.write(KEY_COMMAND_GET_RESUMES + "\n");
                            pw.flush();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.e("MyLog", "onDestroy");
        try {
            if(!socket.isClosed())
                socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Смысл такой:

1. Когда мне нужно что-то с сервера я запускаю сервис, предварительно в интент положив определенные данные;
2. Если я обращаюсь к серверу впервые, то разумеется будет вызван метод `onCreate`, в котором я создаю поток который подключается к серверу и слушает что с него приходит. Когда что-то пришло - возвращает это фрагменту;
3. Происходит вызов метода `onStartCommand`. В него передается `Intent`, в который я заранее положил ключ по которому сервис поймет какую именно процедуру просить у сервера выполнить.

Этот вариант работал пока я пользовался одним фрагментом. Но в нем есть существенный недостаток. Все `Message` я могу отправить только `Handler`-у в `WorkerFragment`. Теперь же я начал обращаться к серверу с других фрагментов и это решение работать не будет. Я не знаю как нужно изменить этот сервис чтобы он знал куда именно ему нужно отсылать результат.

Скажите пожалуйста **как делать** это **правильно**?

Comment: Как вариант -- можете использовать это: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: используйте везде uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) и в фрагменте, и в сервисе. Это будет хэндлер одного и того же главного потока и сообщения будут приходить в него вне зависимости от того, где он объявлен или создан, а точнее во все места... Не забывайте только учитывать жизненный цикл фрагментов и активити...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, тоесть в FragmentA и в сервисе в полях я создаю Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) ? Теперь когда я с сервиса отправляю сообщение, то оно будет доходить до фрагмента? это вроде понятно, но где прописывать реакцию на обработку сообщения? раньше я создавал подкласс хэндлера и переопределял метод "handleMessage".

Comment: Точно также переопределяйте handleMessage там где вам надо. Т.е. в сервисе obtainMessage делаете для хэндлера в сервисе, ловите во в handleMessage хэндлера во фрагменте. Очередь обработки сообщений хэндлера конкретного потока (точнее лупера) одна.